# Navigation bar .active issue.

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue where when You hover over an item on the nav bar it changes it to the color of the .active class that I have set up where its only on red when its on that page.

This is what it looks like When you go to hover over other nav bar items, It doesn't do this if you don't hover over any other item. But the hover color is blue not red.

[image: Red Nav Bar issue]

And This is what it looks like when you hover over an item, than if you hover over another it will change it to red and change your current one your hovering over blue. 
[image: When you hover]

Heres my CSS That is making .active class red:

```
li .active{
background: red;
color:#000;
}
```

Heres the CSS for making the hover Blue

```
 .nav > li {
    position: relative;
    display: block; }
    .nav > li > a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      padding: 10px 14px; }
      .nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #3E50B4; }
    .nav > li.disabled > a {
      color: #777777; }
      .nav > li.disabled > a:hover, .nav > li.disabled > a:focus {
        color: #777777;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: transparent;
        cursor: not-allowed; }
  .nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:hover, .nav .open > a:focus {
    background-color: #3E50B4;
    border-color: #393838; }
```

Heres my HTML for the Nav Bar for the Home.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 smallmenu" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right head_align">
                            <li class="text-white header_li">
                                <a href="index.php" class="active text-white mont font12">Home</a></li>
```

Any Ideas on why its doing this? Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your css is changing the (`#3E50B4`):

```
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #3E50B4; }
```

Exclude this from your css if you don't want the color change on hover.

In case you don't want to change your css, but want your red color setting to override every other, you can apply `!important` on it.

```
li .active{
    background: red !important;
    color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happened because you have not added the background color for active link hover. Apply the background color `red` when you have the `.active` class for the anchor and hover it like below.

```
.nav > li > a.active:hover, .nav > li > a.ative:focus {
    background: red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using bootstrap.  Bootstrap is a little overbearing when it comes to css specificity, and you're not providing enough specificity with `li .active`.

You need to match the bootstrap definition and ensure your definition is after the bootstrap css include:

```
.nav > li > a.active
{
    background: red;
    color:#000;
}
```

The easiest way to find out why it's not doing what you want it to use the browser dev tools (eg in Chrome, select the element then choose Computed, filter to background and it will tell you which rule is creating the effect).